# I'm having a failure to upload images using Typora and PicGO

Tags: image, upload

The error message I encountered was as follows:
Failed to upload image. Error message:
`{"success":false, "message": "upload error. see C:\\\Users\\\17946\\AppData\\\Roaming\\\\picgo\\\picgo.log for more details."}`
I want to upload to my repository on github,I don't know what went wrong?

I thought it was a temporary problem and I restarted the computer and software, but it didn't work.